# Rust Handling Nest Errors - expected struct `Box`, found enum

Tags: rust

I'm working with rdkafka and serde and trying to re-write my code into something more elegant to avoid the ugly nested matches to handle error scenarios. I've come up with the following but struggling to understand how to get it working.

What I'm trying to do, and maybe wrong idea, I'm new to Rust, is to do all the logic around reading the message, reading the payload, processing the payload by reading the JSON, and at any point if that encounters an error I just want to log it out and move to the next message in Kafka.

My first iteration I was just using unwrap to get something working, then moved to match anywhere an error could have returned but that got messy and somehow looked worse than the Go version. I'm trying to get a cleaner approach.

This is the error I'm getting...

```
134 |               let res: Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> = msg_result.and_then(|msg| {
    |  ______________________--------------------------___^
    | |                      |
    | |                      expected due to this
135 | |                 msg.payload().ok_or(Err(Box::new("empty message")))
136 | |                     .and_then(|payload| {
137 | |                         serde_json::from_slice(payload)
...   |
150 | |                 Ok(())
151 | |             });
    | |______________^ expected struct `Box`, found enum `KafkaError`
    |
    = note: expected enum `Result<_, Box<dyn StdError>>`
               found enum `Result<_, KafkaError>`
```

And my code snippet

```
pub fn consume_cms_documents() {

    let consumer: BaseConsumer = ClientConfig::new()
        .set("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        .set("enable.auto.commit", "false")
        .set("group.id", "experimentdocument")
        .set("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
        .set_log_level(RDKafkaLogLevel::Debug)
        .create()
        .expect("invalid consumer config");

    consumer.subscribe(&["CmsDocuments"])
        .expect("topic subscribe failed");

    loop {
        for msg_result in consumer.iter() {
            let res: Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> = msg_result.and_then(|msg| {
                msg.payload().ok_or(Err(Box::new("empty message")))
                    .and_then(|payload| {
                        serde_json::from_slice(payload)
                            .and_then(|e: CmsEvent| {
                                if e.r#type.eq(EXPERIMENT_DOCUMENT_TYPE) {
                                    serde_json::from_value(e.datasource)
                                        .and_then(|exp_doc| {
                                            println!("Document: {:?}", exp_doc);
                                            // todo: call something here to actually process the message and store it
                                            Ok(())
                                        });
                                }
                                Ok(())
                            });
                        Ok(())
                    });
                Ok(())
            });

            match res {
                Ok(_) => (),
                Err(e) => println!("failed to process kafka message {:?}", e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your method payload parsing code into it's own method with the return type `Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>` and using the ? operator to pass errors that you can match with your `match res`?

Comment: Something like this maybe (not tested): https://pastebin.com/3LsAd2gh

Comment: I suggest looking at [`anyhow`](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow) to unify your error types.

Comment: Oh, and [`map_for`](https://crates.io/crates/map_for) to simplify your nested `and_then` cascade (disclaimer: I wrote `map_for`).

Comment: That's the mostunreadable code I've seen in a while. The functional style sometimes makes things simpler, but in other cases it makes them horrendous. Why didn't you just use `?` to early-propagate the errors ?